# Any idea how to solve fast animating background picture

Tags: css, image, animation, background, keyframe

This is my css code for the animating background, but its too fast, everything happens in like a second. please can somebody help me any ideas how to fix that.
I'm quite new here

```
    .one{ 
animation: changeBg 1s infinite; 
width:100%; 
height:450px; }

    @keyframes changeBg{
     0%,100%  {background-image: url("../project1/img/hero1.jpg");
    }
    25% {
       background-image: url("../project1/img/hero2.jpg");
     }
    50% {
       background-image: url("../project1/img/hero3.jpg");
     }
    75% {
        background-image: url("../project1/img/hero4.jpg");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.one{ 
  animation: changeBg 3s infinite; 
  width:100%; /*      ^^^^ */
  height:450px; 
}
```

### Change 1s to whatever duration you want

Can either be in seconds (s), or milliseconds (ms) 
[W3 Schools: animation-duration](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-duration.asp)

Comment: Oh, missed that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

the `1s` in `animation: changeBg 1s infinite;` is your timing.  You can increase that and additionally you can add animation timing function like `ease`, `linear`...etc

Comment: How do I add the linear function cause its really fading slowly?

Comment: you can just do `animation: changeBg 5s infinite linear;` or add on it's own like this... `animation-timing-function: linear;`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function